# Fancybox the requested content could not be loaded iPhone only

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, fancybox

I'm running into a really strange issue with Fancybox. I've used this literally hundreds of times and have never had this issue before.

What I'm doing is quite simple. I'm using the simple method to set a `data-fancybox-href` attribute and then load in a modal.

It works great on desktop, both on my local setup and on production. But for some reason, using my iOS simulator, I'm unable to get the content to show up; the "requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later" message shows up.

The images and hrefs are present when I type them in manually to the iOS simulator. This is a really bizarre issue.

Javascript:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  openEffect: 'elastic',
  closeEffect: 'none'
});
```

HTML:

```
<a data-fancybox-href="images/pic/0185.jpg" class="fancybox stripimg"><img src="images/pic/r/0185@2x.jpg" /></a>
<a data-fancybox-href="images/pic/0106.jpg" class="fancybox stripimg"><img src="images/pic/r/0106@2x.jpg" /></a>
<a data-fancybox-href="images/pic/0012.jpg" class="fancybox stripimg"><img src="images/pic/r/0012@2x.jpg" /></a>
<a data-fancybox-href="images/pic/0175.jpg" class="fancybox stripimg"><img src="images/pic/r/0175@2x.jpg" /></a>
<a data-fancybox-href="images/pic/0124.jpg" class="fancybox stripimg"><img src="images/pic/r/0124@2x.jpg" /></a>
```

Using latest version from Bower and latest jQuery. I saw a few posts that identified the issue may be from loading jQuery more than once; that is not the case on my setup.

The strange thing is, when I set `type: "iframe"` the content actually does load just fine.

Comment: try also adding `data-fancybox-type="image"` to your anchors (or do it programmatically with jQuery `$(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-type","image").fancybox()`)

Comment: @JFK unfortunately that did not work; I see the attribute getting added in the DOM and I tried both programmatically adding it as well as adding it in the raw HTML. Any other suggestions? This is a super weird one.

Comment: @JFK for some reason, when I try different images in the data-fancybox-href, it works fine...I don't get it at all. The fact that the images show up in both mobile and desktop browser at the original HREF, but don't work on mobile is very confusing. For now, I just moved the images to a different directory and it's working now...